# Draw dashed line with solid and empty circle using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, circles, tikzscale

**Problem:**

Trying to get empty circles to work with `tikz` and add text to the right of the circles. I have not been able to find the correct command for these two issues.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, environ}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Scales tikzpicture to text width
% --------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
  \def\tikz@width{#1}%
  \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \BODY
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
  \BODY
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale, xscale=1.3]
    \draw [thick] (0,0) -- (8,0);
    \draw (0,-.2) -- (0, .2);
    \draw (1,-.2) -- (1, .2);
    \draw (2,-.2) -- (2, .2);
    \draw (3,-.2) -- (3, .2);
    \draw (4,-.2) -- (4, .2);
    \draw (5,-.2) -- (5, .2);
    \draw (6,-.2) -- (6, .2);
    \draw (7,-.2) -- (7, .2);
    \draw (8,-.2) -- (8, .2);
    \draw[dashed, {Circle}-{Circle}] (0,-1) -- (4,-1);
    \draw[dashed, {Circle}-{Circle}] (2,-1.75) -- (6,-1.75);
    \draw[dashed, {Circle}-{Circle}] (2,-2.5) -- (4,-2.5);  
    \node[above] at (1,0.25){$-5$};
    \node[above] at (2,0.25){$-4$};
    \node[above] at (3,0.25){$-3$};
    \node[above] at (4,0.25){$-2$};
    \node[above] at (5,0.25){$-1$};
    \node[above] at (6,0.25){$0$};
    \node[above] at (7,0.25){$1$};
    \node[align=right, below] at (7.5,-.4){Text here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}

\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: `\draw[dashed, -o] (0,-1) -- (4,-1)node[right]{VO};` works for me. Add  to preamble `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing everything right when loading `arrows.meta` (since it supersedes `arrows`), you only need to add `[open]` for open circles and `node[right]{...}` for the texts. Of course, I do not know which texts you want and which of the circles should be open, so I added something generic and opened 50% of the circles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, environ}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Scales tikzpicture to text width
% --------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
  \def\tikz@width{#1}%
  \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \BODY
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
  \BODY
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale, xscale=1.3]
    \draw [thick] (0,0) -- (8,0);
    \draw (0,-.2) -- (0, .2);
    \draw (1,-.2) -- (1, .2);
    \draw (2,-.2) -- (2, .2);
    \draw (3,-.2) -- (3, .2);
    \draw (4,-.2) -- (4, .2);
    \draw (5,-.2) -- (5, .2);
    \draw (6,-.2) -- (6, .2);
    \draw (7,-.2) -- (7, .2);
    \draw (8,-.2) -- (8, .2);
    \draw[dashed, {Circle}-{Circle[open]}] (0,-1) -- (4,-1) node[right]{abc};
    \draw[dashed, {Circle}-{Circle[open]}] (2,-1.75) -- (6,-1.75)node[right]{xyz};
    \draw[dashed, {Circle}-{Circle[open]}] (2,-2.5) -- (4,-2.5)node[right]{uvw};  
    \node[above] at (1,0.25){$-5$};
    \node[above] at (2,0.25){$-4$};
    \node[above] at (3,0.25){$-3$};
    \node[above] at (4,0.25){$-2$};
    \node[above] at (5,0.25){$-1$};
    \node[above] at (6,0.25){$0$};
    \node[above] at (7,0.25){$1$};
    \node[align=right, below] at (7.5,-.4){Text here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AndréC I know all that but the OP correctly loads `arrows.meta`, which is appropriate because it is more powerful.

Comment: @marmot Is there a way to get space between the empty circle and the text?

Comment: @kexxcream Yes, of course, you can add a dimension after `right`, replace e.g. `\draw[dashed, {Circle}-{Circle[open]}] (0,-1) -- (4,-1) node[right]{abc};` by `\draw[dashed, {Circle}-{Circle[open]}] (0,-1) -- (4,-1) node[right=3mm]{abc};`.